# pycharm throws "ModuleNotFoundError" for all modules

Tags: python, import, module, pycharm

When I try to run my program pycharm would throw ModuleNotFoundError for every imported module.

[image: error]

I have downloaded the modules through pycharm with settings->Project->Python Interpeter-> the '+' sign

[image: installed module]

when I try to import through the python console with the same interpeter in the same virtual env it works fine.

[image: works fine in console]

Comment: Its because you are running python in a virtual env, youl need to add those modules into the venv to use them

Comment: Are you using the same environment/kernel which you are writing the code in. Usually this hapend when you create a new environment with may be different version of python which might cause an error

Comment: the virtual environment and the kernel are the same